# Not showing partial view result inside table body in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have written code to implement search using ajax in asp.net MVC. I have written an action inside my controller (`Admincontroller`) using partial view which is supposed to fetch data. I want to display the partial view result inside table body in my Index page.

The search function is working fine, but it is not displaying the result inside table body with id `"searchresult"` (Inside `Index` page). instead of that it is giving result. I wanted the result from search in table format. now result is displayed like below in http://localhost:1274/Admin/Search.

```
 2786 Mens L/S 4000
```

here is my Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TestEntityFramework.Models.trProducts>

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    AjaxOptions ajax = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "searchresult",
        Confirm = "Are you sure to start search?",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId="Loadhere"
    };

    }

   <h2>Index</h2>
   <script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
   <script src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
   <div class="panel-heading">
   <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create",null, new{ @class="btn btn- primary" })
   </div>

   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-    hover table-responsive">
    <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prod_type)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prod_name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prod_desc)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prod_price)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prod_qty)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prod_category)
    </th>
    <th></th>
    </tr>

   @foreach (var item in Model) {
   <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prod_type)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prod_name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prod_desc)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prod_price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prod_qty)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prod_category)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id=item.product_id}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.product_id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.product_id })
    </td>
    </tr>
    }

    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Product Id
            </th>
            <th>
                Product Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
        </tr>

       </thead>
       <tbody id="searchresult">
        @Html.Action("Search", new { pr_name = ""  })

        </tbody>
        </table>
      @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", ajax))
       {
       <div id="Loadhere">
        @Html.TextBox("pr_name")
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
       </div>
        }

       </div>
```

and my partialview Search.cshtml looks as below

```
   @model IEnumerable<TestEntityFramework.Models.trProducts>
   @foreach(var m in Model)
   {

    <tr>
    <td>
        @m.product_id
    </td>
    <td>
        @m.prod_name
    </td>
    <td>
        @m.prod_price
    </td>
    </tr>
     }
```

Comment: If your redirecting rather that displaying the results in the same page, it means you do not have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` loaded in the view (or its layout). But its far better to just use one of the `$.ajax()` methods. You can just use `<button type="button" id="search" class="btn btn-primary" >Search</button>` and `$('#search').click(function() { $('#searchresult').load('@Url.Action("Search", { pr_name: $('#pr_name').val() }); });`

Comment: here is my controller action method
          public PartialViewResult Search(string pr_name)
        {
            var details = productdetails.pageproduct.Where(f => f.prod_name.Contains(pr_name)).ToList();
            return PartialView(details.ToList());

Comment: Edit your question (do not add relevant code in comments). But that has nothing at all to do with your issue. Read my last comment!